# Метка filesystem является синонимом метки файловая-система

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Считаю что метка [`filesystem`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) является синонимом метки [`файловая-система`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0/).

Предлагаю исправить данное недоразумение.